# unhashable type: 'slice' error when removing characters from list values in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a list of values pulled in from a website using BeautifulSoup. It looks like this:

```
tables_values1 = soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':'x1'})
print(tables_values1)
```

Output: [123value1,123value2,"123value3]
(Note there was no " or ')

I am trying to slice off the first x characters using the following (which I also found on stackexchange):

```
tables_values = [x[2:] for x in tables_values1]
```

However, this returns:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Could anyone help figure out why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks so much!

Edit: Please let me know if this is a valid list now!

Edit 3: Printing exact repr as requested below:

```
[<td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">136          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">SFD          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">136          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">$33,657,146           </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">9.7          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">$33,657,146           </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">61          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">34          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">5          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">61          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">34          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">5          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">5          </td>, <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">95          </td>]
<td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">136          </td>
```

Comment: `[123value1,123value2,123value3]` is not a valid list.  Could we have the exact output please.  Thank you.

Comment: [<td class="category-1">40,900          </td>, <td class="category-1">GTA, WSD          </td>, <td class="category-1">45,000          </td>, <td class="category-1">4,922          </td>, <td class="category-1">$15,540,013,888           </td>, <td class="category-1">25.7          </td>, <td class="category-1">$999,573,200           </td>, <td class="category-1">$18,581,541,708           </td>]

I would like to strip <td class="category-1"> from each list value.

Comment: Still not a valid list. Please **edit your question** with this information: A valid input list (`table_values1`) and a required output list.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, I am new to programming. Is this an array rather than a list?

Comment: @AlexD  No Python does not have arrays.  Strings are always enclosed with `" ... "` or `' ... '` in lists.

Comment: Lists are very common in python. They look like: `[]`. We note that your example data looks a bit like a list, but the values contained in it are not valid. Did you mean: `["123value1", "123value2", "123value3"]`?

Comment: Ah but when I print, the '...' won't show up? I copied the output from print. I think I understand and will edit accordingly.

Comment: Now that you have changed your sample list to contain strings, the code that you supplied works. Did you mean to convert the items in the list to strings before the slicing?

Comment: Don't edit the output. If there were no quotation marks in the output, don't edit them in; just explicitly say there were no quotation marks.

Comment: Print `repr(tables_values1)` and `repr(tables_values1[0])` and show us what you get.

Comment: Judging by how `find_all` is supposed to work, it looks like your originally claimed output wasn't really copy-pasted from the `print` results like you say it was. If it was, then something really weird is going on. The output in your new edit definitely wasn't copy-pasted either. Show us *actual output* that Python *actually printed*. Don't make it up.

Comment: Note that each value in the output is preceded by <td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">

(not sure why that does not show up in the text)

Answer (score 1):

Those are BeautifulSoup tag objects in your list, not strings. You're trying to slice them as if they were strings. You really should be working with them *as* tags instead of trying to do string manipulation; for example, if you were trying to get the text between the tags, that'd be

```
contents = [x.string for x in tables_values1]
```

where the [`string` attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) is a helper to get the single string child of a tag, if it has one.

---

If you really want to perform your task with string manipulation instead of working through the BeautifulSoup interface, you can convert your tag objects to strings, including the `<td class="..."></td>` part:

```
strings = [str(x) for x in tables_values1]
```

Then you can slice the strings all you want.

Comment: Is `str(x)` the same as `x.name` for tags in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Thank you! When sending these to a csv file, will the fact that they are strings affect ability to manipulate them (i.e. adding and multiplying)?

Comment: That's the topic of another question. Feel free to ask questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @quamrana: No, `x.name` would just be `'td'` here, while `str(x)` would be `'<td class="...">...</td>'`.

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants the contents of a tag, so `str(x)`, but without the `x.name`. In the example list `136` is needed without the `<td ...> </td>` that surrounds it. Is there a `x.body`?

Comment: @quamrana: That could be what they want. We can't really tell; stripping the first two characters off of the contents doesn't seem to make much more sense than stripping off the `<t`.

Comment: This seems to be the requirement given the first comment of the OP under the question.

Comment: It sounds like they might have counted the characters in `<td class="views-field views-field-field-category-value-2018">` and tried to strip the whole tag off with string slicing, in which case they should probably be using `x.string` instead of slicing.

Comment: That's correct! I just wanted to show the text inside the tag.